# Reading JSON or text file in resource folder

Tags: android, file-io, kotlin

I am developing Kotlin app.
I am trying to read text and JSON files which I stored in resource folder(res/raw/file.txt).
Looking at the hierachy of app structure, I put absolute path(../../res/raw/file.txt)  for file reader.

Unfortunately, my app cannot find the file.

Can you tell me how I can read files stored in res/raw? If I store file in wrong directory, can you tell me where to store and how to access them?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to read a file from `res/raw` folder you can obtain `InputStream` by `R.raw.yourfile` id like this:

```
resources.openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile)
```

Or you can open file by Uri:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.your_package/raw/yourfile")
val file = File(uri.getPath());
```

Alternatevily you can put your files in `assets/` folder and get `InputStream` like this:

```
assets.open("yourfile.txt")
```

Comment: very convenient the uri way!